# VS2017 auto adding project configuration platform settings to solution .sln file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for development of a multi-project solution. Every time I do something such as build, change a file, switch branches, sync, etc., the .sln solution file changes. When I look at the Diff to figure out what keeps changing, I see the following gets added in the `GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution` section of my .sln:

> {(guid here)}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
>   {(guid here)}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
>   {(guid here)}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
>   {(guid here)}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU

The guid refers to my project called MyProject, which is a Node.js unit test project. I have not made any changes to this project, and I looked at the master branch and confirmed that the master does not have these extra lines.

I check my Build Configuration Manager and see that all of my projects have `Config: Debug` and `Platform: x64`, as well as `Config: Release` and `Platform: x64`, except for MyProject, which has `Platform: Any CPU` for both Debug and Release. However, when I click the dropdown to change Any CPU to x64, the only item in the dropdown is Any CPU.

Why does this keep happening? It is annoying to have to keep clicking "Undo changes" and wait for the sln to reload.

Comment: This started happening for me after someone else checked the solution file into source control and they had added new project configurations into this section in the solution file: GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution.  Still not sure why it wants to add new ones for me.  If we could figure out what that {{guid here}} guid represents, that would help.